# Python: Can't print/store Int'l characters properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on Python2.7 and grabbing Japanese/Chinese characters from page. It prints fine on Console but when I am storing in a `list` and `dict` it does not and `print(records)` displays as:

> u'portuguese': u'sirena abisgundecheck translation',
>   u'japanese\xa0(r\u014dmaji)': u'm\u0101meiru - abisugunde',
>   u'chinese': u'\u6c34\u7cbe\u9cde-\u6df1\u6e0a\u6208\u8feacheck
>   translation',...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 is notorious for mangling unicode characters. Consider switching to Python 3 which handles all of this natively.

It appears to me that given `dict = {'japanese': u'japanese\xa0(r\u014dmaji)'}` the characters appear the way you presented them when printed straight away (`print dict`), but work better if you do `print dict['japanese']` or first iterate over keys and then print.

Clearly, the u'xxx' format is how unicode strings are represented internally by Python. They are then converted to human-readable form when printed in isolation, but not when they exist as part of a bigger structure.

Comment: Not possible as it's being used in production.

Comment: I see. It appears to me that given `dict = {'japanese': u'japanese\xa0(r\u014dmaji)'}` the characters appear that way you presented them when printed straight away (`print dict`), but they work better if you do `print dict['japanese']` or iterate over keys and print. Could you post some more code pertaining to your specific use case?

Comment: Oh yeah exactly. Accessing the certain key and it prints the character fine.`print(records[2]['chinese'])` prints `水精鳞-深渊戈迪` while `print(records[2])` yields `{u'chinese': u'\u6c34\u7cbe\u9cde-\u6df1\u6e0a\u6208\u8fea'}`

WHy is that??

Comment: Clearly, the u'xxx' format is how unicode strings are represented internally by Python. They are then converted to human-readable form when printed in isolation, but not when they exist as part of a bigger structure.